# Copy and paste to a sheet in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, automation, copy, paste

I want to automate this code :

when a cells is full for each row (Column F), the row is cut and past in the sheet "montre vendu".

And I'm not sure the code work really well.

```
Sub coupercoller()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Variable'

    Dim Sct As Range
    Dim derniereligne As Long
    Dim wsMv As Worksheet
    
'définir les variables'

    Set wsMv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Montrevendu")
    Set Sct = Selection
    derniereligne = wsMv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
'selectionner avec la souris
    Sct.Select
    
'couper la sélection
    Selection.Cut
    
'sélectionner la feuille montre vendu'
    Sheets("Montrevendu").Select
    
'sélectionner la dernière ligne et insérer'
    Range(derniereligne).Select

'Sur la feuille coller'
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
'revenir sur la feuille de départ
    Sheets("source").Select
    
'dévérouiller l'écran
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cut` doesn't just copy, it also deletes. You cannot do `Range(LastRow)`, you could do either `Range("A" & LastRow)` or `Cells(LastRow, "A")`. Do you want to copy the cells or the entire rows of the selection? Is the `Selection` possibly a table or a range? Couldn't you specify it more accurately? Please do clarify, maybe add a screenshot or two.

Answer (score 0):

No need for all those `Select`/`Selection` and just use direct and fully qualified range references

Furthermore, make sure current `Selection` is actually a `Range`, or either the code would fail or you wouldn't get the expected results

```
Sub coupercoller()

    ' check if selection is a valid Range 
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "No range selected", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Montrevendu") ' reference "target" sheet
        Selection.Copy .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' copy secletion and paste it into referenced sheet starting from its column A first empty cell after last not empty one
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Finally, in your code there's no trace of a check for "*when a cells is full for each row (Column F)...*", which your wording is stating as the initial condition
You may need to add it

Comment: thanks for your answers. The code work but I need a automatisation when a cells is full : the code run. And I need a cut and note just à copy. I don't have put the check for the cell because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: as to _"I need a cut and note just à copy"_ then just change `Copy` to `Cut` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cut)

Comment: as to "_"The code work but I need a automatisation when a cells is full"_, you may want to add more detalis in the OP description. But I guess you may google "Worksheet Change event"

Comment: HOOOOO I don't know that exist !!! Incredibel. But it's hard to use.

Comment: Okai definitly to hard for me ...

Comment: Do I need to create a news question to answer to how to do that ? or I can just modify this one ?

Comment: if you found a solution to your own OP, the just add an answer and then mark it as solved
BTW, if you found my answer useful, you may consider to upvote it

Comment: Your answer is really usefull, but I don't know how to use it so not so mutch usefull :')